# Execute file with unknown name

Tags: php

I want to run a php file create from my website that gets unknown filename the name will be increasing everytime, i want to create a phpfile that open this unknown.php run the code in it and after delete the file when it has been openend

what it tried was with fopen en exec and "/path/to/dir/*.php", "r", "unlink"

and same with the url to the directory

when i run the php in browser with the link to it it works

```
<?php

    exec ("/path/to/directory/*.php", "r")or die("Unable to open file!");

?>


now also tried this 


<?php
foreach (glob("/path/to/dir/*.php") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename";
}

exec ($filename);
?>
```

Comment: [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) might help you

Comment: Wait, so you want to run the code from x.php, but access it from a randomly generated URL, each time?

Comment: Well its pretty easy what i want ; the php name will be generated with the order_id but thats unknow how much or when there wil be a order, what i know is it will be a php so every file in that directory needs to be opend or pocessed and after it has been done deleted

Comment: <?php
foreach (glob("/subdomains/Test/daniel/order/*.php") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename";
}

exec ($filename);
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could see the directory where you put your php files as a queue, process them like this:

```
<?php
$files_to_process = scandir('/path/to/dir/');
foreach($files_to_process as $k=>$file){
    file_get_contents("example.com/dir/".$file);
    unlink('/path/to/dir/'.$file);
}

?>
```

This will execute and delete each files in the queue.

Comment: tried your solution didnt worked, could it be because it has to be execudes as a url, like http://www.example.com/dir/file and then enter

Comment: give me your adress i come to kiss you ,was last part of what i was doing and it works, i tried your solution with fopen thought that would be the answer but get_contents did the job :*:*

Comment: @PEst About the Kiss, i'm good thanks :), but an accepted answer would be great ! Unless of course if you think the answer miss something ?

Comment: fopen didnt worked your solution with get_contents did the job :)